# JavaScript: toggle button group not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to implement a toggleable button group into my popup window. It works kinda... but not fully. Heres the code, it is kinda complicated to explain so please enable all buttons in the snippet and then you will see. And yea, i know. The code is very unoptimised, just tried to make it work.
Thanks for any help! :)

```js
document.getElementById("off1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off1")) {
        document.getElementById("off1").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off1";
        
    }
});
document.getElementById("off2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off2")) {
        document.getElementById("off2").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off2";
        
    }
});
document.getElementById("off3").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off3")) {
        document.getElementById("off3").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off3";
        
    }
});
document.getElementById("off4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off4")) {
        document.getElementById("off4").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off4";
        
    }
});
document.getElementById("off5").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off5")) {
        document.getElementById("off5").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off5";
        
    }
});
document.getElementById("off6").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off6")) {
        document.getElementById("off6").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off6";
        
    }
});
document.getElementById("off7").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off7")) {
        document.getElementById("off7").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off7";
        
    }
});
document.getElementById("off8").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementById("off8")) {
        document.getElementById("off8").id = "on";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on").id = "off8";
        
    }
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 95px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 12px; 
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
}
#off1, #off2, #off3, #off4, #off5, #off6, #off7, #off8 {
    background-color: #101820FF;
    color: #fff;
    border:1px solid white;
}
#on {
    background-color: #FEE715FF;
    color:#101820FF;
    border: 1px solid #FEE715FF; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/popup.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="item-toggle-group">
            <input type="button" id="off1" value="jackets">
            <input type="button" id="off2" value="shirts">
            <input type="button" id="off3" value="tops/sweaters">
            <input type="button" id="off4" value="sweatshirts">
            <input type="button" id="off5" value="pants">
            <input type="button" id="off6" value="hats">
            <input type="button" id="off7" value="bags">
            <input type="button" id="off8" value="accessories">
            <script src="../js/toggleButton.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use classes instead. Then you only need one function. When you click a button remove the `on` class from all the elements and then add it to `this` element.

Comment: Can you please explain that in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `id` you can use `class` so that you can use `classList.toggle` method to toggle `on` class on specific button click.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.toggle').forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('on');
  })
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 95px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: #101820FF;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.on {
  background-color: #FEE715FF;
  color: #101820FF;
  border: 1px solid #FEE715FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-toggle-group">
  <input type="button" id="off1" class="toggle" value="jackets">
  <input type="button" id="off2" class="toggle" value="shirts">
  <input type="button" id="off3" class="toggle" value="tops/sweaters">
  <input type="button" id="off4" class="toggle" value="sweatshirts">
  <input type="button" id="off5" class="toggle" value="pants">
  <input type="button" id="off6" class="toggle" value="hats">
  <input type="button" id="off7" class="toggle" value="bags">
  <input type="button" id="off8" class="toggle" value="accessories">
</div>
```

To remove `on` class on sibling elements you can create one function that will return sibling nodes of clicked element and remove `on` class from each of those sibling nodes.

```js
function getSiblings(el, nodes) {
  return [...nodes].filter(node => node != el)
}

document.querySelectorAll('.toggle').forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('on');

    getSiblings(this, this.parentNode.children).forEach(function(button) {
      button.classList.remove('on');
    })
  })
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 95px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: #101820FF;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.on {
  background-color: #FEE715FF;
  color: #101820FF;
  border: 1px solid #FEE715FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-toggle-group">
  <input type="button" id="off1" class="toggle" value="jackets">
  <input type="button" id="off2" class="toggle" value="shirts">
  <input type="button" id="off3" class="toggle" value="tops/sweaters">
  <input type="button" id="off4" class="toggle" value="sweatshirts">
  <input type="button" id="off5" class="toggle" value="pants">
  <input type="button" id="off6" class="toggle" value="hats">
  <input type="button" id="off7" class="toggle" value="bags">
  <input type="button" id="off8" class="toggle" value="accessories">
</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt de-select the other buttons when clicked.

Comment: No no, it was right. It was my fault, i should have expressed myself better. The goal is to enable multiple buttons.

Comment: @stax You can just remove the getSiblings part in that case, the rest will work the same.

Comment: @stax You're welcome, I've wrote both options in answer just in case. Also keep in mind that `id`'s must be unique so you can have only one same id on whole page, for example multiple `on` ids would be invalid html.

Answer (score 1):

Use a data attribute to identify if a button is on and classes to identify the buttons.

Html

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="jackets" data-on="0">
<input type="button" class="button" value="thing2" data-on="0">
<input type="button" class="button" value="thing3" data-on="0">
<input type="button" class="button" value="thing4" data-on="0">
<input type="button" class="button" value="thing5" data-on="0">
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(this.getAttribute("data-on") == "1") {
        this.setAttribute("data-on", "0");
    } else {
        this.setAttribute("data-on", "1");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.button {
  ... css for buttons that are off
}

.button[data-on=1] {
  ... css for buttons that are on
}
```

Using classes makes it generic so you can just add buttons on the fly without adding an event listener for that specific button.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be modifying the ID of your button elements - once two are turned on, you have two elements with the same ID of 'on'.  At this point, when you turn any of them off, only the first element with the ID of 'on' is being set back to the off state (not necessarily the one you clicked to turn off).

Easiest fix is to modify the class of these button elements (not the ID) using:

```
document.getElementById("off5").className = "on";
```

Then also change your CSS to style by class, not by ID

```
.on { /* styles here */  }
```

not

```
#on { /* styles here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead. Then you only need one function. When you click a button remove the `on` class from all the elements and then add it to `this` element

```js
function highlight() {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.replace('on', 'off');
  });
  this.classList.replace('off', 'on');
}

var items = document.querySelectorAll(".off");
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", highlight);
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 95px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 12px; 
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.off {
    background-color: #101820FF;
    color: #fff;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.on {
    background-color: #FEE715FF;
    color:#101820FF;
    border: 1px solid #FEE715FF; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="item-toggle-group">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="jackets">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="shirts">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="tops/sweaters">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="sweatshirts">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="pants">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="hats">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="bags">
            <input type="button" class="off" value="accessories">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `element.classList.toggle('toggle-class')`

```js
function doToggle(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('toggled');
}

var toggleInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var index in toggleInputs) {
  toggleInputs[index].onclick = doToggle;
}
```

```css
.toggled {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="toggle me 1"><br>
<input type="button" value="toggle me 2"><br>
<input type="button" value="toggle me 3"><br>
<input type="button" value="toggle me 4"><br>
<input type="button" value="toggle me 5"><br>
<input type="button" value="toggle me 6"><br>
```